# Spring tool suite JDK 9 issue

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-tool-suite

After importing spring-boot 1.x project into my workspace I got -

[image: JDK 9 issue]

So I has looked for my STS.ini to set it to use JDK 8, but I could not find it.
Running win 10 with 64 bit.

BTW - is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any other way to solve this than to configure your STS.ini file to point to a JDK 1.8 to run STS on. You can grab the latest JDK 1.8 64bit for Windows from various download pages (e.g. the official Oracle one), install that, and configure your STS.ini file to use that JDK.

You can still use a newer JDK level in your projects though. Running STS itself on a JDK 1.8 doesn't mean you can't use JDK 9 or 10 in your projects. That should work independently of the JDK that you use to run the IDE itself (just in case that matters in your case).

Comment: OK, but is I installed STS via eclispe marketplace, I do not have STS.ini file or I just cannot find it.

Comment: that would be the `eclipse.ini` if you just installed the plugin